# SVN merge from trunk to branch after copy of the tree

Tags: svn, merge

We are using SVN for our DB and SSIS development in VS 2017 SSDT. We are working on a big project and have decided to copy an original SVN tree into a new one. Here is the original tree.

```
Folder1
   --->Trunk
   --->Branches
      --->test
      --->uat
      --->prod
```

After the copy, it looks like this

```
Folder2
   --->Trunk
   --->Branches
      --->test
      --->uat
      --->prod
```

After this, we have done quite a bit of work and now I really need to force all changes from Trunk to test branch. I'm ok to just force to overwrite that branch.

How can I go this? Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you have `Folder1`, copied into `Folder2` and you worked in `Folder2`? And do you want merge... from what? Did you read this: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html ?

Comment: Yes, we copied Folder1 to Folder2. So we can continue working on 2 different trees in parallel. There is a lot of work was done in Folder2-trunk and some work in Folder1 and its branches. Now I need forward merge every change from Folder2 to its test branch. It is a massive change. I'm think to just do "merge two different tree". Am I wrong to do it?

Comment: I think it's a "simple" merge (two or three times). I can't see why would should be a specific problem.